# How to make a "post" system on my site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My goal is to have a place where people can submit things publicly in a post system. I currently have an HTML form where people can write down a title and info.

How would I do it so when they submit the form, it pops up as a visual post below the HTML form? I don't want total spoon-feeding here, as I actually want to learn something, but just a bump in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You should give us more information. For example do you use REST API, SOAP etc. you should define us your end-point.

Comment: Depends on the other code. If you have no other javascript at all and just rely on the response to the submit from the php, you have to make it so the php will send back the correct html that includes that post. If you want to immediately show the post and just use the php to store it in a database, use javascript to intercept the submit (or just dont use the submit button), then create some html using the text in the form and insert it. Then do the submit to php manually.

Comment: What is it you call a "post system" ? a forum, a wiki, a blog, a chat , .... ??

Comment: you'll need ajax (popup under the form) and a database for this. You can  use text files but they're a lot of trouble to maintain. This is but one option of many. The question is way too broad.

Comment: Can you show us some code?
You will need to find a way to store the data in a database.

And if you want the post to display immediately after being submitted, you'll probably want to use AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you haven't added `mysql` tag , I am hoping that you know it's basics. or you can google as you build this because this answer just need the very basics of it. First step would be to enter data of submitted form in the database table say `comments`. now don't forget to a a column of `post_id` in this table so you can later show comments specific to that post.

you can do this by adding a hidden input in the form.I am supposing here that you have `post_id` in the address of that post, so you'll get it by `GET` method.

```
<form role="form" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <input name="commentorname" type="text"  required>
    <!--and some other inputs-->
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

then establish the connection using `connection.php`

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");
?>
```

then on action.php you get the data by `$_POST` and enter this into the database

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(post_id,username,comment) VALUES ('$post_id','$commentorname','$comment')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

then final step is to extract the comments on the post page:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='{$id}'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

here `$id` is again `post_id`. and then embed data from `$row` into the html.

As suggested by [fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) in the comments : Since it is open to an SQL injection. real_escape_string() is not enough; it can still be prone to an injection.These [php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  [php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are much safer.

Comment: Good answer, yet if the OP is going live with this and stands to be, they'll definitely need a prepared statement. What you wrote here is open to an SQL injection. `real_escape_string()` is not enough; it can still be prone to an injection. A prepared statement is best.

Comment: thank you for you appreciation. Are you talking about something like this: `$name = $_POST['commentorname'];$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$commentorname);$name = strip_tags($name);`

Comment: You're welcome. That isn't enough. These http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php are much safer.

Comment: you are absolutely right but as the OP says  `just a bump in the right direction would be great` , I wanted to keep this answer short and cover all the basics to make comment feature work. advanced security features are open to explore.

Comment: Yes you're right about that. The question IMHO, is way too broad, but you've given them enough to get started. I on the other hand would not have submitted an answer for a question like this. However, when you post answers with db code, it's best to use a prepared statement right away, and/or use reference links to the php.net website's functions on those and a minimal example. It also has a potential to attract votes, as in "positive" ones ;-)

Comment: You are right. I'm gonna include you suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, for what info I gave, this is awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: can you please accept it then. you know , click on the check-mark on the left of my answer.